How to make a texture pack for Minecraft that works with Sodium?
I have a Minecraft client made on Curseforge: It includes Fabric mods (such as Iris Shaders and Sodium, which I specifically added to use Complementary Shaders with my Fabric client mods). In addition to this, I included Prime's HD Textures, and they all work fine together.
Now, I'd like to test my own texture pack that I am making. I first tried VanillaDefault and used it as a template, but it did not work due to Sodium and the shader which replaced the default shader. I have also tried to make my own resource pack that only included pack.mcmeta and assets/minecraft/textures/block/acacia_door_bottom.png; This didn't run into an error, but it did not seem to be picked up as an update to the client (it didn't show up as a folder in the resource packs).
How can I create this texture pack so it works with my client? I am using 1.21.1 with Fabric mods.

Resource packs are independent to shaders... Are you trying to modify material properties, or just textures? Also, have you tried restarting the game or reloading the resource pack (as in: switch to a different resource pack, and then back)? Also, could you please write a bit more detail about what you did and are expecting? Is the texture not being changed? Also, what is the order of your resource packs?
